# android sqlite query code with multiple selection arguements

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, datepicker

I am building sqlite query arguments with around 20 possible conditions.
what I would like to achieve here is when only few out of 20 condition is set how can I dynamically adjust and remove unused criteria from the query.

```
String selection = ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CR_NUMBER + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_PHASE + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_PRIORITY + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_PERCENT_COMPLETION  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_REGION  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_BU  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_RAG  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_PO_DATE  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DUE_DATE  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CURRENT_BASELINE_DUE_DATE  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_FORECASTED_DUE_DATE  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_ACTUAL_COMPLETE_DATE  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_STATUS  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_REF  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_COST_CENTER  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_COUNTRY  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_PM  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_PM  + " LIKE?" + " AND "
                + ProjectEntry.COLUMN_ENGINEER + " LIKE?"
                ;

        String[] selectionArg = {
                "%" + queryCrNumber + "%",
                "%" + queryPhase + "%",
                "%" + queryCategory + "%",
                "%" + queryPriority + "%",
                "%" + queryPercentCompletion + "%",
                "%" + queryRegion + "%",
                "%" + queryBu + "%",
                "%" + queryProjectName + "%",
                "%" + queryRag + "%",
                "%" + queryPoDate + "%",
                "%" + queryCustomerDueDate + "%",
                "%" + queryCurrentBaselineDueDate + "%",
                "%" + queryForecastedDueDate + "%",
                "%" + queryActualCompletionDate + "%",
                "%" + queryStatus + "%",
                "%" + queryCustomerRef + "%",
                "%" + queryCustomerCostCenter + "%",
                "%" + queryCountry + "%",
                "%" + queryCustomerPM + "%",
                "%" + queryPM+ "%",
                "%" + queryEngineer + "%"
        };
```

Comment: you can build String dynamically using conditions  @JK Seo

Comment: can you post function where you set all selection args , so i can make function for dynamic string @JK Seo